# How to pass Server Name dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic, ssrs-2008

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @servername NVARCHAR(255)

SET @servername = '[s-printstream]'

--Drop Table #Actual
CREATE TABLE #Actual 
(
    jobnumber INT,
    firstNameCounts VARCHAR(25),
    lastNameCounts VARCHAR(25),
    address1Counts VARCHAR(25),
    address2Counts VARCHAR(25),
    cityCounts VARCHAR(25),
    stateCounts VARCHAR(25),
    zipCounts VARCHAR(25),
    inHomeDateCounts VARCHAR(25)
)

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #actual (jobnumber,firstNameCounts,lastNameCounts , address1Counts, address2Counts, cityCounts, stateCounts, zipCounts, inHomeDateCounts) '
SET @sql = @sql + ' Select s.jobnumber, count(s.firstName) AS [firstNameCounts], Count (s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], Count (s.Address1) As [address1Counts], Count (s.address2)-Count (address2) AS '
SET @sql = @sql + ' [address2Counts], Count (s.City) AS [cityCounts], Count (s.State) AS [stateCounts], Count (s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], Count (jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts] '
SET @sql = @sql + ' From' + ' @servername ' + '.[tdis_417133]' + '.[dbo].[tblStandardFinal] s '
SET @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].[tblJobTicketActions] jb '
SET @sql = @sql + ' ON jb.psFlagJobNumber = s.jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' where jobNumber = @jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' group by jobNumber '

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    ,N'@JobNumber Varchar(25)'
    ,@JobNumber = 417133
```

Could anyone please help me find out how I would pass my server name dynamically as well as the database name? When I try to do it, I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@servername"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't surround your variables with single quotes.  `+ ' @servername ' + ` should be `+  @servername  + `

Answer (score 1):

or pass @servername value into sql command

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    ,N'@JobNumber Varchar(25),@servername nvarchar(255)'
    ,@JobNumber = 417133,@servername=@servername
```